# Как найти дубликаты в списке?

Tags: java, алгоритм, коллекции, поиск

Помогите пожалуйста с алгоритмом поиска и вывода дубликатов в списке на Java.

```
ArrayList<String> allUsers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("User1", "User2", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User4", "User4", "User5", "User5"));
```

На выходе должно получится:

```
{"User2", "User4", "User5"};
```

Если есть возможность с комментариями, что откуда берется и т.д.
И будет хорошо, если получится несколько вариантов решений.

Comment: Нужно найти все элементы, которые повторяются больше одного раза?

Comment: "И будет хорошо, если получится несколько вариантов решений." - и Вашим почерком?

Comment: алгоритм - не вопрос. проходите по массиву и считаете количество повторяющихся элементов, складывая результат в Map, где ключ - элементы вашего массива, а значение - количество повторений каждого в массиве. Теперь проходите по созданной Map и отбираете только те, где значене больше единицы (повторяются больше одного раза) и складываете в какой-то лист или сет или куда душе угодно. Вот и весь алгоритм

Comment: Отсортиовать массив и просмотреть его. Одинаковые будут рядом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На английском Stack Overflow есть вопрос: [Identify duplicates in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414667/identify-duplicates-in-a-list). В ответах к нему приводится множество решений на любой вкус.

Короткий способ, через streams API:

```
List<String> duplicates = allUsers.stream()
    //группируем в map (пользователь -> количество вхождений)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
    //проходим по группам
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    //отбираем пользователей, встречающихся более одного раза
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
    //вытаскиваем ключи
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    //собираем в список
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Способ «вручную» через цикл и два множества:

```
//множество с дубликатами
final Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
//множество для отслеживания повторяющихся элементов
final Set<String> tracking = new HashSet<>();
//пробегаемся по всем пользователям
for (String user: allUsers) {
    //добавляем их во множество для отслеживания
    //если не получилось добавить, то значит пользователь уже встречался в списке
    if (!tracking.add(user)) {
        //в этом случае добавляем его во множество дубликатов
        duplicates.add(user);
    }
}
```

Вместо множества дубликатов тут можно использовать список.

Comment: Спасибо! Второй способ интересный, и отдельное спасибо за комментарии.
Вопрос, а возможно ли реализовать вручную без использования HashSet?
Т.е. поиск и вывод значений, где значение в массиве встречается более одного раза. Но при этом использовать только цикл. и например обычные массивы.)

Comment: @Nikita Можно. Вместо множеств создаем два списка (`ArrayList` это именно список, а не массив), проверять существует ли элемент в `tracking` (циклом или `contains`) — если существует, добавляем в дубликаты, если нет в `tracking`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

На котлине можно так

```
fun getItemsMoreOne(list: List<String>) = list
    .groupBy { it }
    .filter { it.value.size > 1 }
    .map { it.key }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё и так:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Duplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> allUsers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("User1", "User2", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User4", "User4", "User5", "User5", "User4"));
        Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();

        Set<String> setOfDupl = allUsers.stream().filter(e -> !stringSet.add(e)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        setOfDupl.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Неоптимально, но очень понятно, если с лямбдами знакомы конечно